# Проблема с include_once

Tags: php, html, веб-сервер, include

Решил сегодня пересесть с XAMPP и наконец настроить свой веб-сервер. Все установил, настроил (как смог), перенёс один из проектов для теста, но столкнулся с проблемой.

Сервер установил тремя строчками:

```
sudo apt install apache2
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql php-xml php-curl
```

Есть небольшой шаблон:

```
<head>
    <?php include_once "./components/plugin_files.html";?>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <?php include_once "./components/navigation.php";?>
    </header>
    <div id="main_container">
        <main>
            <div id="page_content">
                <?php include_once "./contents/$folder/content.php";?>
            </div>
            <aside>
                <?php include_once "components/calendar.html";?>
                <?php include_once "components/daily_task.php";?>
            </aside>
        </main>
    </div>
    <div id="fader"></div>
    <div id="loader" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Проблема с include_once, первые два вложения отрабатывают и на странице появляется навигация и подгружаются необходимые скрипты:

Навигация:

[image: Навигация]

Скрипты:

[image: Скрипты]

А всего остального как-будто не существует, на боевом сервере все ок, и на локальном XAMPP тоже, переменная $folder формируется в файле "navigation.php" и с ней все ОК.

Более чем уверен, что проблема в настройках сервера, но не знаю куда копать

UPD:

Весть HTML-код после третьего include_once тоже пропал (исчезли fader и loader):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ./components и components/ - это разные папки?

Comment: Нет, это я просто экспериментировал

Comment: посмотрите логи апача, дбавьте где-нить вначале ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Пишет, что файл "contents/main/content.php" неожиданно закончился на строке 175, а там пустая строка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, разобрался, спасибо за помощь.
Проблема в том, что у меня в contents/main/content.php были вложены короткие php-тэги, которые отключены в php.ini.
Включил тэги:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перезапустил apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

PROFIT!